# SQL Server - add foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have an already existing database with tables. I added foreign key relationships (because they were referring data from another table, just that relationship was not explicit in the way tables were created) for one of the tables.

How does this change impact the existing database? Does the database engine have to do some extra work on existing data in the database? Can this change be a "breaking change" if you already have an application that uses the current database schema?

Comment: How is "existing data" "added" in the database? It's already there isn't it?

Comment: @bart Yes data is already there. Just that before primary-foreign relationship was not explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added a referential constraint, then the database stores that constraint and ensures it is maintained. For example, if table A has a foreign key referring to table B, then you cannot insert a row into table A that refers to a key that does not exist in table B.

Comment: Yes, but in case I apply that relationship after I already have the data. Will the server check every tables elements so as to ensure that the relationship is correct ?

Comment: @Ghita: Yes, SQL Server will do this for you (unless you explicitly tell it not to)

Comment: As @marc_s said, you normally cannot apply a constraint that is broken in the first place. You first need to fix the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed some extra work (though very minimal, depending on your database server) to enforce referential integrity. In practice, the performance impact is almost never something you'd notice.

It can be a "breaking change" - your client code may insert data that doesn't meet the referential constraints. If the DB allowed you to create the constraints in the first place, it's not likely, but it is possible.

Comment: I see high activity in the sql server instance after adding the referential constraint. I can't tell exactly but could it be because the server is checking the integrity after my change ? It's a very large database..

Comment: Are the primary keys and foreign key columns indexed? Under the hood, SQL Server is almost certainly doing a "select * from parent table where primary_key = ????" for every insert/update.

Comment: Mainly the primary key is indexed. The foreign key is not indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [`WITH NOCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463.aspx) when creating a foreign key constraint:

> The `WITH NOCHECK` option is useful when the existing data already meets
>   the new `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, or when a business rule requires the
>   constraint to be enforced only from this point forward.
>
> However, you should be careful when you add a constraint without
>   checking existing data because this bypasses the controls in the
>   Database Engine that enforce the data integrity of the table.